# How many caps do I really need?

Tags: fallout-4

My charisma is very high (11 with outfit and beer, before mentats) and I have Caps Collector 2 already. I am just under 40K caps now, bringing gear with value/weight of over 10:1 And I am thinking that maybe I am too much of a hoarder/scrapper as I do not  run into good gear to buy from merchants.

So are there any must buys that I should save for? Or could I forget about picking up each Institute Laser and just focus on only on more expensive stuff to sell occasionally to have lower inflow of caps?

Comment: You could always buy up large stocks of rare ammo and fusion cores to go on rampages.

Comment: How long is a piece of string?

Comment: The title is sort of different then the question. Also, this is really a matter of opinion. But personally, I'd say keep saving for the special armor/weapons that you can get.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I saw the manticore armor parts which were at 16k caps each. If you invest into shops, you can buy even more expensive equipment, I've seen a modified, legendary weapon for 22k.

I think you never have enough money, but when you hit 100k, you'll have enough for a while. I don't think there is anything in the game which costs more than 25k.

Comment: "I don't think there is anything in the game which costs more than 25k." Do you have a source for this other than speculation?

Comment: @FuriousFolder that is why he said it as speculation, if he had a source for it I am sure he would include it.

Comment: @FuriousFolder As you can see, I wrote "I think". But i got over 150 hours now, and i didn't see anything that pricey

Comment: @YUNOWORK, Ok? I've got 160+, does that mean I'll *never* see an item that expensive? This entire question is extremely subjective.

Comment: @FuriousFolder No, it doesn't mean that you *never* will with *certainty*. That's why it says "I don't think". If you ever run across something, leave a comment. I've never seen anything that expensive either.

Comment: Even if you looked at the game files and confirmed nothing is more than 25k... you never know what could change with expansion packs or mods...

Comment: Getting the high end gear involves knowing about the Level 4 merchants, getting them, and setting them up to sell the Level 4 stuff.  If you don't know how to do that then you obviously won't see them.

Comment: @nhgrif It can always only talk about the current state. Bothering with the future would be completely nonsense and this question would be closed for off topic :P

Comment: @YUNOWORK I know.  I'm actually on *your* side of this comment debate and I'm proving your point to the most extremes.  You have 150+ hours and haven't seen anything over 25k.  It isn't the most objective, but that's a pretty decent measure.  My point (to those arguing with you) is that a mod or expansion is probably more likely to introduce a more expensive item than you discovering one in the next 150+ hours of game play.

Answer (score 12):

It entirely depends on how you want to play the game. If you want to buy the various rare armor parts from vendors you'll need lots. If you want to buy the experimental weapons from vendors you'll need lots. If you want to build large sprawling settlements without farming the materials then you'll need to buy them, which needs lots. Some ammos are quite rare out in the wild (plasma cartridges and cryo ammo) so you'll need to buy those, which will cost lots.

You can easily spend 100k caps on a full set of gear and there are several other expensive items in the game also, and that's if you're fine with just one set of gear. If you want to collect all of the sets then this is going to add up pretty quickly.

On the other side of the argument, you can play the game using only loot that you've prised from the cold dead corpses of those who crossed you, scavenging ammo and switching between weapons as you deplete your limited supply of bullets and completely ignoring pleas from settlers in the wastelands as deathclaws decimate their homes - and if you play like this, then you don't really need any, you'll always end up with more caps than you spend.

Comment: I'm glad you can actually spend money now.  I ALWAYS play FO:NV and end up with over half a million caps because there is literally nothing to spend it on.  Plus there is the repair glitch where I steal back all my monies...

Answer (score 5):

There are some Legendary armor piece for sale at a traveling merchant costing 10K+ each. 
Furthermore building the highest tier shops tend to cost a lot of caps (up to 4K, perhaps even more). 
In general though, you might be better of picking up usefull Junk, instead of weapons and armor.

Comment: +1 for Junk suggestions - most of my caps go towards Copper/Oil/Adhesive based junk parts